# Generate sinusoidal patterns in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How can I generate the following [image] in Matlab?

and How generates these patterns :
[image: image2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
f= % you choose
A=repmat(sin(linspace(0,f*(2*pi+pi),256)),[256 1]);

imshow(A)
```

[image]

Explanation: `linspace` creates linearly spaced point to control the size of the image (change 256 by something else). `repmat` repeats the sin wave every row if the image.

Change the initial and final angle to control the behaviour in the corners

Comment: @Niloufar Consider accepting is at valid then ;). Also please do not add things to an question  when someone has answered it. Accept the answer (if it helped) and open a new question

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with this site.

Comment: could you please explain how can I generate that other sinusoidal patterns ? I wrote this for generating sinusoidal patterns :
fs = 0.1; 
W = 100;
H = 100; 

img1 = zeros(100, 100);
for m = 1 : W
    for n = 1 : H
        img1(n, m) = sin((2*pi*fs*m)+pi/2);
    end
end
how can I generate other patterns?